# External Domain with Micro Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I know this is a much asked question in regards to Cloud Foundry in general with disappointing responses as of current, and even though I get the idea it is not possible with an instance of  Micro Cloud Foundry, I want to ask just to make sure. Is it possible to configure an external domain on an instance of Micro Cloud Foundry without tunneling from a cloudfoundry subdomain?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible with a stock Micro Cloud Foundry VM. However, you could SSH into the VM and modify the necessary files so it will respond to a domain of your choice. Look here for pointers: http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20404628-how-does-url-addressing-work

Comment: I found cloud_controller.yml at /var/vcap/packages/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/config and updated the external_uri value from api.vcap.me and also attempted to update the local_route value to the desired IP. Still getting the error "VCAP ROUTER: 404 - DESTINATION NOT FOUND" though. Am I updating the right config?

Comment: Got it figured out. Have to walk myself through exactly how still, but that was the right config. Thank you very much Glenn for taking the time to point me in the right direction.